# Does NAT affect the other networks on the router?

Tags: nat

Does NAT affect other networks on the router?

If I have two subnets on a router and I want to access the non-natted network through natted interface.  Will it have any affect at all?

I.e.will I have any trouble accessing the normal non-natted network from r1?

r1
|
nat outside  network
|
r2-----------------------(normal network non-natted)
|
|
nat inside network

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>  r1
>  |
>  nat outside network
>  |
>  r2-----------------------(normal network non-natted)
>  |
>  |
>  nat inside network
> ```
>
> ... will I have any trouble accessing the normal non-natted network from r1?

Assuming you are routing on all devices correctly, R1 *can access* the `normal network non-natted`.  To be explicit...

Assume:

- `nat outside network` is 198.51.100.0/24
- `(normal network non-natted)` is 203.0.113.0/24
- `nat inside network` is 10.1.1.0/24
- R1 has a route to 203.0.113.0/24
- R2 has a routes to anything on or behind R1

*Packet flow*:

If R1 receives a packet for 203.0.113.50, it will forward the packet to R2.  R2 has a connected interface for 203.0.113.0/24, so it looks up the layer2 adjacency information for 203.0.113.50<sup>1</sup> and forwards R1's packet to `normal network non-natted`.  As long as 203.0.113.50 has a default pointing to R2, and R2 can reach the IP subnet which originally sourced the traffic behind R1, then there are no problems.

In summary, NAT is a local operation between two interfaces on the same router / firewall.  NAT does not affect the reach-ability of interfaces that are not participating in NAT.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>using ARP tables, if `normal network non-natted` is Ethernet.</sub>

Comment: Is this "bridging" the connection?

Comment: The traffic described in my answer is routed